# Galaxy S4 memory management

Tags: android, memory, galaxy

We have specific problem with this device (Samsung S4). Every launch of the application (even if the app is in background and is brought to the front again) takes about +1MB of RAM. I know this is a very general question, but if someone has similar problem...

Thank you for any response

Update: The memory leak is on other devices too (but S4 eats more memory, probably because more resources are needed for its resolution)

We are using ABS with main `FragmentActivity` and 6 Fragments. Application is skinnable (skin are set for each fragment in `onCreateView()` method). Every launch of the application or listing through fragments eats more and more memory until the device starts freezing and it's totally useless.

In the  app we don't use static contexts, applicationContexts or static resources.

Comment: how exactly do you measure memory usage? does it cause you any problem? what is your real issue?

Comment: Can you please explain more. Its hard to get your exact concern in the question. Unhappy with the memory or with the device.? Or Samsung.?

Comment: mvp: we measure it in Application->list of running....the real issue is, that after many starts of application (or walking through the application between fragments), the application take all available memory and the device is useless until reboot.

Comment: AkShat: I updated qustion..see top